# Improve performance when doing multiple insertions

Tags: optimization, quill

I am working with quill to create a collaborative editor. I'm handling my text as a list of characters. Therefore, the insertion of 10,000 characters results in 10,000 call to `quill.updateContent` with the following delta:

```
{ ops: [
   { retain: somePosition },
   { insert: someCharacter }
  ]
}
```

I made some comparison between using updateContents inserting characters one by one, using updateContents inserting characters by batchs or insertText.
Here is a benchmark http://jsfiddle.net/pLwk5qLd/11/. The result shows that I should insert by large part of text.

My question is then, is it quill's job to do this optimization or should I try to factorize my insertions into larger insertions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quill's `updateContents` method is synchronous so if you tell it to insert a character the only correct behavior is for it to insert a character.

If you'd like to batch, take a look at Delta's [compose](https://github.com/ottypes/rich-text#compose) method.